# Core data advise placing existing entity inside existing entity

Tags: core-data

Looking for some advice and pointers. I am creating a card app. Like top trumps there are different decks. In core data I have three entities:

Player ->> Decks ->> Cards

what I want to do is when the app loads create 30 cards. Then a player. Then the player creates a deck from  30 cards. The user can only pick 11 of these cards. So my question is, how would I assign existing card entities to the deck?

Comment: have you established a Core Data relationship between the Deck and Card Entities?

Comment: Yes I have as above Player related to many Deck Related to Many Cards. Do you think I should link the cards directly to the player. I am thinking There is a default deck. When the game starts the Player gets a In play deck. All I want to know really is if I create a new deck how to I add existing Card entities without creating new entities? If you know what I mean. If for instance the ace a spades exists in the default deck can I put a copy or access to this in the InPlay deck using core data methods

Comment: Post any code that you've tried so far, but you should be doing something like [deck addCardsObject:card]. This will add the card to that relationship such that it will be returned by deck.Cards

Comment: Agh yes so basically I would just persist the cards I want from default deck and add them to the inPlayDeck? I havent tried it yet I was just looking for the best way to do it. I have set up the data model and created the deck etc

Comment: created an answer from my comment. Feel free to accept it as the correct answer if it was helpful to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate a To-Many relationship, Deck to Cards in your case, you will use `[deck addCardsObject:card]`. This will add Card objects to the relationship such that they will be returned by `deck.Cards` and the deck will be returned by `card.Deck`. This is how you can go about associating the card objects to the deck. You may want to duplicate the needed cards from your "default deck" when creating a new deck, so your default deck holds all possible cards, and new decks can contain a subset of those cards without interfering with the original relationship of cards to the default deck.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do this but it was advice on best practice I was after really. Rather than duplicate the entities for the inPlay Deck I was wondering if there was another way. I guess the only other way is to do it at code in game level creating a player array and computer array. Thanks anyway.